# Inicializar array con Spring y uso de autowire

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Tengo una gran duda, y es como puedo inicializar un array en Spring ya que si haces un new técnicamente ese objeto no sera controlado por Spring, para inicializar un array necesitas declarar su tamaño y esto no se como hacerlo en Spring.

pongo ejemplo

```
@Component("Naranja")
 public class Naranja implements Frutas{


@Autowired
String [] prueba;

@Override
public String getPrueba() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void setPrueba(String[] prueba) {
    this.prueba = prueba;
}


}
```

Comment: La pregunta natural sería ¿con que valores lo quieres inicializar?, técnicamente hablando si tienes un "bean" de spring que tiene un método que devuelve un arreglo puedes hacer la inicialización invocanco al método de ese bean, otra forma sería tal vez que tienes una cadena en algún archivo de configuración y deseas partirla y convertirla arreglo en la inyección, eso también lo puedes hacer. Pero como te digo, depende de conque quieras hacer la inicialización

Comment: Si te refieres a usar la anotacion @Value, mas o menos lo entiendo pero no entiendo como puedo inicializar un array vacio. ni como puedo declarar su tamaño.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la anotacion @Configuration de spring e indicar  el objeto/bean que quieres injectar ya que es evidente que Spring no sabe con que implementacion instanciar tu arreglo

Estoy suponiendo que estas usando spring boot asi que te dejo este ejemplo

En  la clase prinicipal de spring boot he colocado la anontacion @Configuration si quieres tener una clase aparte no  hay problema seguira funcionando de todas formas.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }


    //Este metodo se encarga de generar el bean a ser injectado
    @Bean
    public String[] produceArray(){
        String [] data = {"dummy1","dummy2"};
        return data;
    }

}
```

Tu clase con el atributo a ser injectado

```
@Component("dummy")
public class Dummy {

    @Autowired
    private String myArray[];


}
```

Comment: yo me refiero a inicializar mi array sin ningun dato , simplemente como hacer String[] myArray = new String[5] por ejemplo, tambien si no me equivoco puedes usar la anotacion @Value para inyectar valores en un array no? , soy bastante nuevo en esto

Comment: Tu mismo te has repondido cambia  String [] data = {"dummy1","dummy2"}; por  String [] data = new String[5]; y listo.

Comment: pero al aplicar un new, no estaría controlado por el contenedor de spring?

Comment: No lo estaría, pero no todos los new tienen que estar controlados por Spring. ¿Que quiero decir?. En una aplicación empresarial tú anotas tus clases de acceso a datos usando @ Repository, tus servicios como @ Service tus controladores como @ Controller pero si vas a crear un DTO o un POJO eso lo haces a mano salvo un caso muy particular inicializar un arreglo como vacío es más fácil hacerlo con un new.

Comment: Hola Alvaro, tu respuesta me gusta, asi que no tiene por que ,el que todos los objetos esten manejados por Spring entiendo, es mas o menos la respuesta que busco, pero me gustaría ver si tienes algún ejemplo de lo que dices.